# Insert legend for functions matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a function with a loop of three variables S, T, L. Each of those variables have a small value, middle value, and big value (for instance Ss, Sm, Sb). Then by using function(formula), I calculated 27 (every value with each other) functions that depend on the distance. The plot looks well, however, I can not plot legend with labels to it. I would like to have legend 'Sm, Tm, Bm' or 'Sm, Tb, Bm' for each function.

```
#variables
S = namedtuple('S', ['b', 'm', 's'])
T = namedtuple('T', ['b', 'm', 's'])
L = namedtuple('L', ['b', 'm', 's'])

s = S(b=0.00168, m=0.00112, s=0.000560)
t = T(b=750.0, m=645.0, s=550.0)
l = L(b=0.07, m=0.05, s=0.02)


distance = np.zeros((100))
result = np.zeros((3, 3, 3, 100))

def jimmy_jao_formula(m: int, sx: float, tx: float, lx: float):
    Ho = 2
    w = 0.26
    p = (1.0/math.sqrt(2)) * (((lx/tx)**2.0 + (w*sx/tx)**2)**(1/2) + (lx/tx))**(1/2)
    Hx = Ho * math.exp(-p*m)
    return Hx  

for mi, m in enumerate(range(0, 3000, 30)):
    print(f'Working on distance {m} - step {mi}')
    for si, sx in enumerate(s):
        for ti, tx in enumerate(t):
            for li, lx in enumerate(l):
                hx = jimmy_jao_formula(m, sx, tx, lx)
                #formula Jimmy Jao
                result[si, ti, li, mi] = hx 
                distance[mi] = m

# plot the result.
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

for a in range(3):
    for b in range(3):
        for c in range(3):
            plt.plot(distance, result[a, b, c, :])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use another `enumerate`, for example `for a, la in enumerate(['Ss', 'Sm', 'Sb'])`. Then you can construct the label via `label = ','.join([la, lb, lc])` and attach it to the plot via `plt.plot(..., label=label)`. And don't forget to call `plt.legend()` once you're done.